# Rails validation on new form already done before it is submitted

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am adding validation to my posts in my Rails project. Everything works well for edit but on the new form, the alert div already appears before the form is actually submited. How can I fix it in a way that the div only appears on submission of the form if validation returns false.
Thx ;)

posts_controller

```
def new
    @post = Post.new
end

def create
    post = Post.new(post_params)
    if post.valid?
      post.save
      redirect_to post_path(post.id), success: "..."
    else
      @post = post
      render 'new'
    end
 end
```

new.html.erb

```
<h1>Nouvel article</h1>

<% if @post.invalid? %>
  <div class="alert alert-danger">
    <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
      <%= message %><br>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Titre de l'article</label>
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %><br />
    <label>Contenu de l'article</label>
    <%= f.text_area :content, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">...</button>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may add `changed?` check to your template:

```
<% if @post.changed? && @post.invalid? %>
  <div class="alert alert-danger">
    <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
      <%= message %><br>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This works partially since I don't see the red alert div when I arrive in the form but I don't see it when I should now if I dont' pass the validation (leave name blanck for example).

Comment: Right, original version did not correct in all cases. May you try new version? Hope new one will work right.

Comment: Back to initial, the red div is there when I arrive on the page.

Comment: Strange. May you check in Rails console: 
post = Post.new; 
post.changed?

Comment: it returns false.

Comment: I found the solution: I replaced the invalid? by .errors.any?     --  <% if @post.errors.any? %> -- But thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you use `#invalid?` this method invokes validation before you assing any attributes. You need to replace if `@post.invalid@` with if `@post.errors.any?`